# How do I add a product to the cart of a specific user in WooCommerce using API?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm creating an endpoint to add products to the carts of respective user, however every time I do so, the old product is replaced. Is it not adding several products to the user's cart?

```
function add_product_to_cart() {
    global $wpdb;
    $cartObj         = new WC_Cart();
    $tbl_wc_sessions = $wpdb->prefix .'woocommerce_sessions';
    $user_id         = isset($_REQUEST['user_id']) ? $_REQUEST['user_id'] : '';
    $product_id      = isset($_REQUEST['product_id']) ? $_REQUEST['product_id'] : '';
    $quantity        = isset($_REQUEST['quantity']) ? $_REQUEST['quantity'] : '';
    $variation_id    = isset($_REQUEST['variation_id']) ? $_REQUEST['variation_id'] : 0;
    $product         = wc_get_product($product_id);

    // Get Data from WooCommerce Session Table
    $wc_session_data = $wpdb->get_row('SELECT *  FROM '. $tbl_wc_sessions .' WHERE session_key='. $user_id);
    $session_value   = unserialize($wc_session_data->session_value);
    $cart_items      = $session_value;

    // Get Data from WooCommerce User Cart Meta
    $meta_cart_items = get_wc_cart_user_meta($user_id);

    // Get existing product's ID
    $product_arr = array();
    foreach (unserialize($cart_items['cart']) as $key => $value) {
        array_push($product_arr, $value['product_id']);
    }

    if(in_array($product_id, $product_arr)) {
        $response = array('status' => 'failed', 'message' => 'Product already exist in cart.');
    } else {
        if($product->get_type() == "variable") {
            $cart_item_key = $cartObj->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id);
        } else {
            $cart_item_key = $cartObj->add_to_cart( $product_id, $quantity);
        }
        
        $final_cart_1  = unserialize($cart_items['cart']);
        $final_cart_2  = unserialize($meta_cart_items['cart']);
        $cart_item_obj = $cartObj->cart_contents[$cart_item_key];

        $new_cart_item = array(
            'key'               => $cart_item_obj['key'],
            'product_id'        => $cart_item_obj['product_id'],
            'variation_id'      => $cart_item_obj['variation_id'],
            'variation'         => $cart_item_obj['variation'],
            'quantity'          => $cart_item_obj['quantity'],
            'data_hash'         => $cart_item_obj['data_hash'],
            'line_tax_data'     => $cart_item_obj['line_tax_data'],
            'line_subtotal'     => $cart_item_obj['line_subtotal'],
            'line_subtotal_tax' => $cart_item_obj['line_subtotal_tax'],
            'line_total'        => $cart_item_obj['line_total'],
            'line_tax'          => $cart_item_obj['line_tax']
        );

        $final_cart_1[$cart_item_key] = $new_cart_item;
        $final_cart_2[$cart_item_key] = $new_cart_item;

        // Update in WC Session Table
        $cart_items_1['cart'] = $final_cart_1;
        $serializedObj = maybe_serialize($cart_items_1);
        $wpdb->update($wpdb->prefix . 'woocommerce_sessions', array('session_value' => $serializedObj), array('session_key' => $user_id));

        // Update in WC User Cart Data
        $cart_items_2['cart'] = $final_cart_2;
        $serializedObj = maybe_serialize($cart_items_2);
        update_user_meta($user_id, '_woocommerce_persistent_cart_1', $serializedObj);

        $response = array('status' => 'success', 'message' => 'Added product to cart successfully.');
    }

    wp_send_json($response);
}
```

I'm not sure what went wrong, or if there is a more authentic way to go about it also let me know if my code is authentic or not?